# How to run EF Core migrations on SQL Server database using Docker?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

On a Mac I have a Net Core 2.1 Class Library with a few Entity Framework migrations.

I need to use Docker to run SQL Server and update the database with the previews migrations.

I added a docker-compose.yml file to my project:

```
docker-compose.yml
src
  data
    project.data.csproj
```

The docker-compose.yml file is the following:

```
services:
  data:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
  image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
  environment:
    SA_PASSWORD: "Pass.word123"
    ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

At the moment this is not working.

How can I run EF Core migrations on SQL Server using docker in a Mac?

Comment: Off the top of my head there's two ways, have Docker execute `dotnet ef database update` during the container build or at run time you can use `Database.Migrate()`, which would suit your case?

Comment: I use dotnet ef database update

Comment: What you're asking for is in discussion [in this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/issues/89)

Comment: It's a good question, but I don't think there's a solid solution at this time.

Comment: As @AdamVincent suggested, runtime migration looks like natural solution to me. If you for some reason want to run migration by hand, add some parameter to program/appsettings to control the behaviour

Comment: I finally found a solution to this problem here in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60129303/using-dotnet-ef-with-docker-and-asp-net-core-3-1?rq=3

Answer (score 3):

You need to add below lines in Confiure of startup file. It will executed when the application is started. It will update all the migration files to database.

```
using (IServiceScope scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDBCOntext>().Database.Migrate();
            }
```

This worked for me.