# Using dotnet-ef with docker and asp.net core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework, docker, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to run my application written in asp.net core 3.1 on docker. I need to create database using migrations. While executing `dotnet ef database update;` command I get:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
* You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
* You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
* You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

As I understand I need to install dotnet-ef tool. What is a correct way to do it in the container?

Comment: Not exactly. I get an error: dotnet-ef: command not found

Comment: The problem was that there is a need to type ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools" instead of RUN export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

Comment: Great - if you think the other thread doesn't answer your question, you should put an answer here. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Like @harili said, you have to install it and additionally add it to the PATH environment variable.

From Dockerfile:

```
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
```

Comment: confirmed this is the final solution to let dotnet-ef work in the docker build, without exposing the path into the environment variable the dotnet-ef won't work.

Comment: It works. Happy that found this solution after a night of fiddling with dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe you didn't installed the EF tools :

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

And added the Environment PATH as @Vočko suggested :

```
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
```

Comment: not working, as it wasn't added into PATH